# Does groups.list api in google Admin context, list indirect groups as well?

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I want to know if there exist an api which would give all the groups(direct and indirect/nested) for a user.

groups.list seems to only give direct groups, Is there any api which has this functionality?

in the google blog it doesn't say anything for indirect membership.